# order and cycles of perfect shuffle of 52 cards

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is the shuffle:

$$1,2,\cdots,52$$

is turned into

$$1,27,2,28,\cdots,26,52$$

when I try to write the cycles of this shuffle, I get a LOT of cycles, for example:

$$(2\ 3)(27 \ 2)(26\ 51)\cdots $$

in order to compute its order, I have to write it in its disjoint cycles. How do I find such cycles? Also, how this can be generalized? Do I really have to write all cycles, and then follow then to see when they're gonna close?

What I'm trying:

$2\to 3 \to 5 \to 7 \to \cdots 25$ so we have a cycle of 12 numbers. Is it rigth?

Comment: For one, $(2\ 3)$ isnt a cycle because $3$ goes to $5$, as you mentioned. Also, if I understand correctly, $5$ goes to $9$, not $7$. This might just be one of those problems you should just write out. For example, you get a cycle like $(2\ 3\ 5\ 9\ 17\ 33...)$ and then you need to figure out where $33$ goes. Point being, this may just be a messy problem that you can't simplify.

Comment: @ElliotG according to the rule, card $n$ goes to $2n-1$ for $n\le 26$ and to $2(n-26)$ if $n\ge 27$. So $33$ goes to $2(7) = 14$? Shouldn't the cycle be closed at $33$? I've read somewhere that the order must be $8$.

Comment: You have to continue the cycle. So (2 3 5 9 17 33 14 27) would be the complete cycle, since 27 goes back to 2.

Comment: @MihirSinghal nice,t hank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the logic you mentioned above you have:

$(2\ 3\ 5\ 9\ 17\ 33\ 14\ 27)$

Then the next cycle would be $(4\ 7\ 13\ 25\ 49\ 46\ 40\ 28)$

then $(6\ 11\ 21\ 41\ 30\ 8\ 15\ 29)$

and $(10\ 19\ 37\ 22\ 43\ 34\ 16\ 31)$

and $(12\ 23\ 45\ 38\ 24\ 47\ 42\ 32)$

and $(20\ 39\ 26\ 51\ 50\ 48\ 44\ 36)$

then oddly the pair $(18\ 35)$

and of course $(1)(52)$.

That covers every number. I didnt mean to write that all out but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a cycle of $6$ or something because that would change things up.

As it is, the order is the LCM of the length of the cycles. Thus, the order is still $8$ despite that cycle of two.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite that simple, these are the disjoint circles:

(2 3 4 9 17 33 14 27 2)

(4  7 13 25 49 46 40 28)

(6 11 21 41 30 8 15 29)

(10 19 37 22 43 34 16 31)

(12 23 45 38 24 47 42 32)

(20 39 26 51 50 48 44 36)

(18 35)

I don't know of any method other then writing it out. Maybe something including modulus, would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the first and last cards, which are not moved, and renumber the others $1,2,\dots,50$, then this shuffle sends $a$ to $2a\pmod{51}$, so the order is the smallest $n$ such that $2^n\equiv1\pmod{51}$, which is $n=8$.

Then the anomalously short cycle $(18,35)$, which becomes $(17,34)$ under my renumbering, can be seen to be because $51=17\times 3$ and the multiplicative order of $2\pmod{3}$ is $2$ rather than $8$. Since the multiplicative order of $2\pmod{17}$ is still $8$, the cycle corresponding to $3$, the other factor of $51$, doesn't have an anomalous order.